# Conditional expectation conditioning on conditional variable

Tags: conditional-expectation

I wanted to confirm my understanding of the conditional expectation- intuitively it is the average of R.V given information of the conditioning variables.

In particular, given random variables $D$, $S$, $X$ and considering the conditional random variables $Z_1 = D|S$ and $Z_2 = X|S$.

I am trying to understand if the conditional expectation of $Z_1$ conditioned on $Z_2$ is equal to the following the conditional expectations $\mathbb{E}[Z_1|Z_2] = \mathbb{E}[D|S|X|S] = \mathbb{E}[D|S,X]$

Answer (score 0):

In principle $D|S$ does not make sense, but we could understand it as the same random variable $D$ now defined on the space $\Omega\mid S$, that is, the same space $\Omega$ but now with probability $P_ {\Omega/S}$ (probability on $\Omega$ conditioned by $S$). With that interpretation, the equality $\mathbb{E}[D|S|X|S] = \mathbb{E}[D|S,X]$ would hold.

Comment: I know what $P(A|B)$ is when $A,B$ are events, namely $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ which gives rise to a new probability measure on $\Omega\,.$ Notation does not matter. What new probability measure we get when $B$ is now a random variable $S$ I have absolutely no clue. OP plus your answer read like something non mainstream to say the least.

Comment: Well, except for pathological cases, $A\rightarrow P_{\Omega/S}(A)=E[I_A(\omega)|S]$ is a probability over $\Omega$ for each $S=s$.

Comment: So far so good but the notation $\Omega/S$ seems not necessary. Regarding OP, is $D|S$ perhaps a notation for $D=f(S)$ (where $f$ is the famous Doob-Dynkin deterministic function) ?  I don't get what you and OP mean by $D|S$ otherwise. If my assumption is true so far then a similar function $g$ exists for $X|S$ and $\mathbb E[f(S)|g(S)]$ should also be  a deterministic function of $S\,:$ In short $\mathbb E[f(S)|g(S)]=h(S)\,.$

Comment: The OP doesn't say that $D$ or $X$ is a function of $S$, nor do I think he's trying to express $E[D|S]$ by $D|S$. It is logical to understand $\Omega/S$ as the same $\Omega$ but now with probability $P_{\Omega/S}$ (a different one for each $S=s$) and $D|S$ and $X|S$ as the same variables $D$ and $X$ but now on $\Omega/S$. In this case, $E[(D|S)|(X|S)]$ makes perfect sense, which would be the expectation of $D$ conditioned by $X$ but referred to $\Omega/S$. It is then easy to see that $E[(D|S)|(X|S)]=E[D|X,S]$.

Comment: I think it would be a lot better if we did work like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182311/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-with-conditional-probability-expectation) instead of  pondering what that OP might have thought using an inexplicable notation.

Comment: Not able to prove the above equality, maybe?

Comment: Not able to see the mathematical rigor in $D|S$ that I am expecting. As long this is not happening I am not even *willing* to prove anything.